# Javascript a game of q and a

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Using JavaScript only.
I have an array of four questions and an array of four answers and an array of four wrong answers.
I use an array due to order.
When the first question appears, the computer will generate a random number and based on this number put the correct answer in the left or right and put the wrong answer in the other spot.
I register two event handlers on the left and right div's containing those answers.
The individual will select the left or right div based on the question and after the four questions, I will tell you how well you did.

My issue is how to determine which side they chose and if it is right or wrong. I can use event.target.id to determine what the person selected, but how to compare that to the right answer knowing it is random??

I am so new... did I say new.. here is my code to show I tried.. I think its simple, but mind block
I did not finish the rightwrong eventlistener. AND I know the camelCasing, but I wanted to get a rough cut first

```
window.onload = function () {
    var questions = new Array();
    questions[0] = "This is the first question";
    questions[1] = "This is the second question";
    questions[2] = "This is the third question";
    questions[3] = "This is the fourth question";

    var answers = new Array();
    answers[0] = "first answer";
    answers[1] = "second answer";
    answers[2] = "third answer";
    answers[3] = "fourth answer";

    var garbage = new Array();
    garbage[0] = "first garbage";
    garbage[1] = "second garbage";
    garbage[2] = "third garbage";
    garbage[3] = "fourth garbage";

    var k = 0;
    var q = document.getElementById("questionId");
    var a = document.getElementById("left");
    var g = document.getElementById("right");
    var nxtquestion = document.getElementById('nextquestion');

    nxtquestion.addEventListener('mousedown', nextquestion, false);
    a.addEventListener('mousedown', rightwrong, false);
    g.addEventListener('mousedown', rightwrong, false);

    function nextquestion() {
        for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
            q.innerHTML = questions[k];
        }
        randomize(k);
        k++;
        if (k > questions.length) {
            q.innerHTML = "Great, you have finished.  Please reload the page to play again!";
            a.innerHTML = "";
            g.innerHTML = "";
            nxtquestion.style.display = "none";
        }
        return;
    }

    function randomize(k) {
        var randomizer = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

        if (randomizer <= 5) {
            a.innerHTML = answers[k];
            g.innerHTML = garbage[k];
        } else {
            g.innerHTML = answers[k];
            a.innerHTML = garbage[k];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>chapter 1</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="regart.css">
<script src="regart.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<img class="center" src="regart.jpg" width="278" height="113" alt="regart" />
</header>
<div class="middlesection">
<p id="questionId" class="question">Let's Play RegArt!<br /> Choose either left or right for the correct answer.<br /> To begin, click on the 'Next Question' button. </p><input type="button" id="nextquestion" value="Next Question" />
<p id="howmany"></p>

</div>

<div>
<div class="answerleft" id="left"><p>Left</p></div>  <div class="answerright" id="right"><p>Right</p></div>
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
</body>
</html

Here is the CSS... the image will be missing but not important
header, footer, nav
 { display:block; }

html,ul, li, div, h1, h2, h3, p, img
 {margin:0; padding:0;}


body 
 { width:80%; margin:auto; max-width:960px; font-size:100%; background-color:#401d36;}

header { height:120px; background-color:#0f9fbf; }

img.center {display:block;margin:0 auto;}


.middlesection { background-color:#f2e085; padding:20px 20px 0 20px; height:200px;border-style:dashed; color:#401d36; border-width:thin;}

p {font-family:Baskerville, "Palatino Linotype", Palatino, "Century Schoolbook L", "Times New Roman", serif; font-size:1.2em; padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:30px;}



.answerleft {border-style:dashed; color:#0f9fbf; float:left; width:35%; padding:5%; height:200px; font-size:3em;  }
.answerright {border-style:dashed; color:#0f9fbf; float:right; width:35%; padding:5%; height:200px; font-size:3em; }
```

Comment: I would suggest you putting a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net so people can play with what you already have (with the HTML too)

Comment: Some more info would be welcomed...

Comment: I added it all here.. sorry.. the hard part is with addeventlistener and choosing the right answer by selecting the right or left div and not using any buttons????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code you provided misses one vital function. however I have created a fiddle you can check. This I think will solve your problem and you can carry on from there.

```
function randomize(k) {
        var randomizer = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

        if (randomizer <= 5) {
            a.innerHTML = answers[k];            
            g.innerHTML = garbage[k];
            a.addEventListener('mousedown', rightAnswer, false);
            g.addEventListener('mousedown', wrongAnswer, false);
        } else {
            g.innerHTML = answers[k];
            a.innerHTML = garbage[k];
            g.addEventListener('mousedown', rightAnswer, false);
            a.addEventListener('mousedown', wrongAnswer, false);
        }
    }

    function rightAnswer(){
        alert('You are right');
    }

    function wrongAnswer(){
         alert('You are wrong');
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pallab/ACXPN/embedded/result/

Comment: will try everyone later but thanks for ideas and input.. it helps Ironically when I used "i" it would go to the fourth question but with k, it returns each question.. odd.. fyi

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to set something on the element itself and then check for that. Or use a different event handler for each element (you'd have to remove and then re-add them every time the right answer swapped sides).

But an easier way would be to just store the id of the correct element in a global variable then check that, something like this:

```
var rightAnswerId;

function rightwrong(e) { 
    if (e.target.id == rightAnswerId) {
        alert("CORRECT");
    } else { 
        alert("WRONG");
    }
}

function randomize(k) {
    var randomizer = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);


    if (randomizer <= 5) {
        a.innerHTML = answers[k];
        g.innerHTML = garbage[k];
        rightAnswerId = 'left';
    } else {
        g.innerHTML = answers[k];
        a.innerHTML = garbage[k];
        rightAnswerId = 'right';
    }
}
```

There are various other solutions, including storing the current question and comparing the clicked elements contents to the correct answer for that question.

I put my solution into a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceDog/3US2Q/), that might make it easier for someone to come up with something better.

(I changed the event from `mousedown` to `click`, which made more sense for the demo but it depends on exactly what you want to happen).

You also might want to call `nextquestion` on page load to go immediately to the first question. Again, depends on what you want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

i'm quite shure you wanna use `k` instead of `i` as index in your for() statement...
anyway:

> but how to compare that to the right answer knowing it is random??

use another variable to store the right answer's position

```
...

var right_side;

...

function randomize(k) {
    var randomizer = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

    if (randomizer <= 5) {
        a.innerHTML = answers[k];
        g.innerHTML = garbage[k];
        right_side = "left";
    } else {
        g.innerHTML = answers[k];
        a.innerHTML = garbage[k];
        right_side = "right";
    }
}
```

then in your `rightwrong` eventlistener check the `right_side` value